# How can I use single transaction with multiple query in repository mode in nestjs-typeorm

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a setup for my NestJS application in which I am using typeorm with a PostgreSQL database. In the setup, I am using repository mode to query the database. Now I want to use database transactions with my queries, but I am not able to use transactions because I am using one transaction with multiple queries from different repositories, and a transaction uses an entity manager, which has to be used to query the database in order to access the same transaction for all the queries in the scope.

**Entity One**

```
@Injectable()
export class EntityOneService extends BaseService<EntityOne> {
  repository: Repository<EntityOne>;
  constructor(private connection: Connection) {
    super();
    this.repository = this.connection.getRepository(EntityOne);
  }
}
```

**Entity Two**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Connection, Repository } from 'typeorm';

import { EntityTwo } from '../entities/lesson.entity';
import { BaseService } from './baseService/base-service.service';

@Injectable()
export class EntityTwoService extends BaseService<EntityTwo> {
  repository: Repository<EntityTwo>;
  constructor(private connection: Connection) {
    super();
    this.repository = this.connection.getRepository(EntityTwo);
  }
}
```

This is how to initialize the repository from a database table. Now I want to query the database using transaction in repository mode.

```
const entityOne = await this.entityOneService.find()
const entityTwo = await this.entityTwoService.find()
```

I want to query both with the same transaction. I have user `sequelize` before typeorm, and in sequelize there is a method named `transaction` which can used as follows.

```
this.sequelize.transaction(async transaction => {
    const entityOne = await this.entityOneService.findAll({transaction})
    const entityTwo = await this.entityTwoService.findAll({transaction})
})
```

I want to do something like that in typeorm, if possible how can I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, where I can use the repository and transaction just like sequelize, it is using the manager provided when we start a transaction, there is a method `withRepository` inside the manager object, it can be used to do query using a specific repository. So what I have done is created a BaseService and everytime I have to query the database I pass the manager with in the function as last parameter which is optional as well. There I use the manager and do the below.

```
manager.withRepository(this.repository).<queryFunction>()
```

Thats it, If you want an example let me know I will implement it and share in a github repository.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70140732 I think this is an example for a solution with multiple repositories.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

## Transactions

- Creating and using transactions
- Using `QueryRunner` to create and control state of single database connection

### Creating and using transactions

Transactions are created using `DataSource` or `EntityManager`.
Examples:

```js
await myDataSource.transaction(async (transactionalEntityManager) => {
  // execute queries using transactionalEntityManager
});
```

or

```js
await myDataSource.manager.transaction(async (transactionalEntityManager) => {
  // execute queries using transactionalEntityManager
});
```

Everything you want to run in a transaction must be executed in a callback:

```js
await myDataSource.manager.transaction(async (transactionalEntityManager) => {
  await transactionalEntityManager.save(users);
  await transactionalEntityManager.save(photos);
  // ...
});
```

### Using `QueryRunner` to create and control state of single database connection

`QueryRunner` provides a single database connection.
Transactions are organized using query runners.
Single transactions can only be established on a single query runner.
You can manually create a query runner instance and use it to manually control transaction state.
Example:

```js
// create a new query runner
const queryRunner = dataSource.createQueryRunner();

// establish real database connection using our new query runner
await queryRunner.connect();

// now we can execute any queries on a query runner, for example:
await queryRunner.query("SELECT * FROM users");

// we can also access entity manager that works with connection created by a query runner:
const users = await queryRunner.manager.find(User);

// lets now open a new transaction:
await queryRunner.startTransaction();

try {
  // execute some operations on this transaction:
  await queryRunner.manager.save(user1);
  await queryRunner.manager.save(user2);
  await queryRunner.manager.save(photos);

  // commit transaction now:
  await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
} catch (err) {
  // since we have errors let's rollback changes we made
  await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
} finally {
  // you need to release query runner which is manually created:
  await queryRunner.release();
}
```

There are 3 methods to control transactions in `QueryRunner`:

- `startTransaction` - starts a new transaction inside the query runner instance.
- `commitTransaction` - commits all changes made using the query runner instance.
- `rollbackTransaction` - rolls all changes made using the query runner instance back.

Source: https://typeorm.io/transactions

Comment: Yes, I have seen this example and went through the documentation, but my use case is different. I want to use the transaction with multiple repositories.

Comment: Repeating a documentation that doesn't answer the original problem is not helpful.